# System.Data.OracleClient Missing From .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net-4.0, enterprise-library

I'm having trouble building my .NET 4.0 application.  Getting this warning:

> The primary reference "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data,
>   Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an
>   indirect dependency on the framework assembly
>   "System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the
>   currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve
>   this problem, either remove the reference
>   "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a
>   framework version which contains "System.Data.OracleClient,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". EBRX

The solution has three projects in it, all of which are pointing at the 4.0 framework (not client).  Still getting the error.  Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance,
Brandon

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you have a reference to System.Data.OracleClient:

[image]

Just for your notice:

The Types in System.Data.OracleClient (.NET Framework 4) namespace are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the .NET Framework.
As you can see on [https://msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oracleclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [http://blogs.msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx).